# Need help setting up pfsense in ESXi

Tags: esxi, pfsense, vsphere

I've been having this trouble for a while. I've tried several times to get it to work, and I cannot find the solution online so I figured I would need to ask.
I have a box running ESXi, and on it I have a few VMs. They all use the same on-board NIC, but I also have a 2-port NIC in the computer as well. I initially got it because I wanted to try playing with pfsense. Of the 2-port NIC, one will go to my cable modem (Cisco DPC3008) and the other will go to an 8-port switch.

The two ports are, according to vSphere:
vmnic1 - WAN (when I plug this into the modem, it does show the ip address here)
vmnic2 - LAN

and according to pfsense:
WAN  -> em0 -> (I never get an ip address here)
LAN  -> em1 -> 192.168.1.254/24 (This is statically set)

I cannot ping 192.168.1.254 from any computer on the network, and pfsense cannot ping anything else including other VMs. vSphere shows that the port I'm using for WAN does get the ip address when plugged into the modem, but pfsense doesn't get that IP address on the port. I really don't know what to try next. It kind of seems as though the NIC ports are not being properly associated with the interfaces within pfsense. Does that sound right? How do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.